# How to make $("#foo").not("#bar").text() work?

Tags: jquery

It seems `.text()` doesn't care about `.not()` or I'm not understanding either how jQuery's chaining works or how `.not()` works.

Is there better way to filter out `$("#bar")` from `$("#foo")` and get that text content?

```js
t = $("#foo").not("#bar").text()

$("#output").text(t)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p><span id="foo">Hello <span id="bar">World</span></span></p>
<p>EXPECTED OUTPUT: Hello</p>
<p>ACTUAL OUTPUT: <span id="output"></span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: in other words, your code gets the text from any element who's id is `foo` as long as its id is not `bar`

Comment: An element can have only one ID present.

Comment: If I were to change it to `<span id="foo">Hello <i>World</i></span>`, then doing `$("#foo").not("i").text()` still displays `"Hello World"`.

Comment: @hobbes3 `$('#foo').not('i')` is checking that the `<span id="foo">` specifically isn't an `<i>`, and it isn't.

Comment: Oh... then how do I filter out `<i>`? Via `.filter()` and `:not()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how **.not()** works. The docs says that it:

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

So, it should be used to filter a **set of elements**, not **the contents of an element.**

For example:

```js
t = $(".foo").not(".bar").text()

$("#output").text(t)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p>
    <span class="foo">Hello</span>
    <span class="foo bar">World</span>
  </p>
  <p>EXPECTED OUTPUT: Hello</p>
  <p>ACTUAL OUTPUT: <span id="output"></span></p>
</body>
```

There's many options to achieve what you want and each solution will depend on other factors involved in your code. You could for example do this (but its fairly inefficient):

```js
t = $("#foo")
  .clone() // Avoid changing the element on the DOM
  .find("#bar")
  .remove()
  .end() // get back to the #foo chain
  .text()

$("#output").text(t)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p>
    <span id="foo">Hello <span id="bar">World</span></span>
  </p>
  <p>EXPECTED OUTPUT: Hello</p>
  <p>ACTUAL OUTPUT: <span id="output"></span></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `.contents()` and then filter out the elements that you don't want using jQuery's `.not()` function version and then get the `.text()`.

```js
t = $("#foo").contents().not( $("#bar") ).text();

$("#output").text(t)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p><span id="foo">Hello <span id="bar">World</span></span>
  </p>
  <p>EXPECTED OUTPUT: Hello</p>
  <p>ACTUAL OUTPUT: <span id="output"></span></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get text node only from ID

```js
t = $("#foo").contents().filter(function(){ 
  return this.nodeType == 3; 
})[0].nodeValue
$("#output").text(t)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p><span id="foo">Hello <span id="bar">World</span></span></p>
<p>EXPECTED OUTPUT: Hello</p>
<p>ACTUAL OUTPUT: <span id="output"></span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: down comment ??

Comment: I think it's because you're hardcoding the element's order.

Comment: @hobbes3 still the answer is a valid answer and show the right way of getting the correct output